# Pytest freezes the console?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

I have a python project and I installed pytest to test my code. But I have a problem when execute the command `pytest tests`, the console freezes and I have to kill it.

My `pytest.ini` is

```py
[pytest]
pythonpath =
    "."
testpaths =
    tests
filterwarnings =
    ignore::DeprecationWarning
```

I tried with

```
[pytest]
testpaths = tests
addopts = --verbose
```